# Expression: Bag of doorknobs

Tags: expressions

I believe that I heard this on some TV show.  The context was in referring to someone's face or body.  Lumpy? Similar sounding to a bag of hammers or spanners.  The doorknobs would sort of look like a mushroom.

Comment: Probably a derogatory reference to a person's intellect.

Comment: Or maybe a fat, pudgy face, bulgy cheeks.  Or maybe they look like they’ve been hit in the face with a bag of doorknobs.

Comment: Or maybe this is not a known expression, but just made up for that TV show.

Comment: It should be noted that "doorknob", in the US, is commonly used to mean "idiot".  (Eg, "What a doorknob!")  So describing someone as a "bag of doorknobs" may simply imply that the guy is an idiot several times over.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. What is your question here? Are you asking what the expression means?

Comment: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+face+like+a+bag+of+spanners

Answer (score -1):

In the US calling someone a “door knob” means they are stupid.  Bag of door knobs is used to illicit the image of cellulite.

Comment: illicit -> elicit